# jqGrid How to use EditUrl

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid to maintain a database in MySQL using jSON data. I'm able to display the data in the grid but when I try to add or edit a data row through the modal form I get a message saying "Url is not set". But what is the editurl suppose to contain? mysql insert statements? I'm using the grid's predefined add and edit functions.

Also, if you take a look at the trirand demo [page](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) under Manipulating then under Grid Data. They specify their url as url:'server.php?q=2' and their editurl:"someurl.php" They never say what the someurl.php contains. This is where I get lost and I can't find a resource to give me any hints as to what is suppose to be in the editurl php file.

Thanks for any advice.

**UPDATE:**
Code in my editurl php file: I put the POST values from the col model in variables. I only need insert and update statements in the switch statement. Take a look at my insert statement to see which one I should be using. I also have to make you aware that I'm not listing all the columns in the database but I'm listing all the columns that the user sees in the grid. The first insert statement is commented and it states the columns that the values are suppose to be inserted based on their order. The second insert statement is following the order that is in the database. Where you see ' ' are the columns that I didn't want to display to the data grid for the user to see because that information wasn't relevant.

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost"; 
$dbuser = "root"; 
$dbpass = "**********"; 
$dbname = "codes"; 

// connect to the database
$mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Error conecting to db.");

$div = $_POST['div_id'];
$l2 = $_POST['l2_id'];
$l1l2 = $_POST['l1l2_id'];
$l1l3 = $_POST['l1l3_id'];
$l2l3 = $_POST['l2l3_id'];
$beg = $_POST['exec_beg'];
$end = $_POST['exec_end'];
$csa = $_POST['csa_id'];
$area = $_POST['area_id'];
$areadesc = $_POST['area_desc'];
$shortdesc = $_POST['short_desc'];
$longdesc = $_POST['long_desc'];
$enabled = $_POST['avail_ind'];


switch($_POST['oper'])
{
    case "add":
         $query = "INSERT INTO divcodes values ($div,'',$l1l2,$l2,$l1l3,$l2l3,$beg,$end,'',''$csa,$area,$areadesc,$shortdesc,$longdesc,$enabled,'','','','','',''";
        $run = mysql_query($query);
    break;

    case "edit":
        //do mysql update statement here 
    break;
}
```

When I set the editurl to my php file and I try to add new row of data to the grid it gives me internal server error 500. I don't know how to debug it any further and the error 500 is such a general error.

I thought that since I was using the predefined operations of the grid (add/edit) that the grid would just know to perform an insert or update statement into my database but it looks like that's not the case?

**UPDATE TAKE 2:** I changed the syntax to use the mysqli extension. Once I restructured my insert statements I stopped getting the 'Internal Server Error Code 500'. When I click add new record then fill in test data then click on submit the modal window disappears like the data has been added to the grid. But no where in the grid can I find the data (maybe the grid is not reloading with the new data). I checked phpmyadmin and the new row is no where to be found. When I edit an existing row and click submit the dialog box stays open but I'm not getting the error 500 which is a relief.

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost"; 
$dbuser = "root"; 
$dbpass = "**********"; 
$dbname = "codes"; 

// connect to the database
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname) or die("Error conecting to db.");

$div = $_POST['div_id'];
$l2 = $_POST['l2_id'];
$l1l2 = $_POST['l1l2_id'];
$l1l3 = $_POST['l1l3_id'];
$l2l3 = $_POST['l2l3_id'];
$beg = $_POST['exec_beg'];
$end = $_POST['exec_end'];
$csa = $_POST['csa_id'];
$area = $_POST['area_id'];
$areadesc = $_POST['area_desc'];
$shortdesc = $_POST['short_desc'];
$longdesc = $_POST['long_desc'];
$enabled = $_POST['avail_ind'];

switch($_POST['oper'])
{
    case "add":
        $query = "INSERT INTO divcodes (div_id,l1l2_id,l2_id,l1l3_id,l2l3_id,exec_beg,exec_end,csa_id,area_id,area_desc,short_desc,long_desc,avail_ind) values ($div,$l1l2,$l2,$l1l3,$l2l3,$beg,$end,$csa,$area,$areadesc,$shortdesc,$longdesc,$enabled)";
        mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    break;

    case "edit":
        $query = "UPDATE divcodes SET div_id=$div,l1l2_id=$l2,l2_id=$l1l2,l1l3_id=$l2l3,l2l3_id=$l2l3,exec_beg=$beg,exec_end=$end,csa_id=$csa,area_id=$area,area_desc=$areadesc,short_desc=$shortdesc,long_desc=$longdesc,avail_ind=$enabled";
        mysqli_query($conn,$query); 
    break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Where are you keeping this php file, in applation or at sever. If server, then where in server. I am using jboss.

Comment: I am keeping my php file next to my JSP file and on submit, I am getting 'error Status: 'Not Found'. Error code: 404' on top of popup window and on console I am getting, no mapping found for request with URI  [/myapp/some.php] in distacherservlet with name 'myApp'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `editurl` is the PHP file that will do your `INSERTS`, `UPDATES` and `DELETES`.

There are several parameters passed to this file including the parameter: `oper` which will be either `add`, `edit` or `del` depending on which operation you did.

In your PHP file (the `editurl` file) I would just do a `switch`:

```
switch ($_POST["oper"]) {
    case "add":
        // do mysql insert statement here
    break;
    case "edit":
        // do mysql update statement here
    break;
    case "del":
        // do mysql delete statement here
    break;
}
```

Also passed to that file will be all of your data from that row in name:value pairs, just like the `oper` parameter. The `name` will be the `index` property you defined in your `colModel` array when you setup your grid.

So if you had a column (from the `colModel`) that looked like:

```
{
    name: 'name1',
    index: 'name1',
    width: 95,
    align: "center",
    hidden: false
}
```

In your `editurl` PHP file, you can access that column's value to build your queries above by using:

```
$_POST["name1"]
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any further questions. I struggled with this part of jQGrid just like you are so I know the pain!! lol

**UPDATE**

Your MySQL Insert statement is incorrect. You do not need to include every column in that exists in your table, just the ones that are required (the columns that can't be `null`).

For instance, I have a table (tableName) with three columns:

- ID (required, not null)
- Name (required, not null)
- Phone (not required)

If I want to perform an insert onto this table, but I don't want to insert anything into the `Phone` column, my Insert statement would look like:

`INSERT INTO tableName (ID, Name) VALUES (123, "Frank")`

On the left side of `VALUES` is where you specify which columns you will be inserting into. On the right side of `VALUES` are the actual values we will be inserting.

Here is a simple, helpful link on MySQL syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

As you can see, in that first example on that link, they don't specify which columns, meaning they will be inserting data into ALL columns. In your case, that is not what you want, so I would check out their second example, which does specify the columns you are inserting into.

Comment: I really appreciate your advice. It makes sense but I'm trying to structure my insert statement but confused as to which format I should take. Please see my update.

Comment: @klm10 Sorry for the confusion! Your `editurl` PHP file will contain your own MySQL `INSERT` `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements. Refer to the `switch` statement above - you need to build your MySQL statements in each of those cases for `add` `edit` and `delete`

Comment: Let me look into Firebug and I'll get back with you. Thank you!

Comment: @klm10 sounds good! Firebug is your best friend when working with jQGrid - also, I prefer the simple Firebug console in Chrome over Firefox. Most of the things Firefox's Firebug can do are unnecessary for our needs.

Comment: I ran Firebug using Chrome and on the console tab it says 'POST editdivisions.php 500 Internal Server Error 31ms' It looks like it does hit the editdivisions.php file which is what my editurl is set to. But there is nothing in the either the Response or HTML tabs.

Comment: @klm10 ok, this is good! So jQGrid is in fact reaching your `editdivisions.php` file. When you expand the line that says `POST editdivisions.php 500 Internal Server Error` do you see all of the parameters from your grid? Also, make sure you see the `oper` parameter. If you see all of these parameters and everything there looks good, then you are getting the 500 Internal Server Error because of an error somewhere in your `editdivisions.php` file. Do you use an IDE that can step through/debug code such as [**Netbeans**](https://netbeans.org/features/php/index.html)?

Comment: Yes, I do see all the parameters including the oper variable. I'm using Netbeans as my IDE. When I try to debug through the grid file which is an html file it doesn't seem to want to walk through the file I suppose because there is no php code to walk through. Also, you can you take a look at my insert statements in the my code posted above to see maybe that's where it's gagging in the code.

Comment: @klm10 Ok, to step thru that code, you will need to put a breakpoint in your `editdivisions.php` file - not the HTML file where the grid is setup. Also, at first glance I can see you do have a syntax error in your MySQL Insert. You are missing a comma right before the `$csa` variable.

Comment: Thanks for seeing the missing comma. But is that the correct format for the insert statement. I've seen it done different ways. Do I have to list out every existing column in the database or can I just list the ones that I display in the grid? and the 'mysql_query($query)' is correct?

Comment: @klm10 I just updated my answer, see the updates. And yes, `mysql_query($query)` is correct. Also, be careful to close the parenthesis and such in the query. Your uncommentted INSERT statement has no closing paren. I would completely redo that, following what I laid out above.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me on this issue. Please see my 'Update Take 2' above.

Comment: @klm10 you're welcome. I would put a breakpoint on the line that runs your INSERT query: `mysqli_query($conn,$query);` and before it runs, grab the value of `$query` and try to run it directly in PHPMyAdmin. Does the record get inserted when you do that? If not, then there still must be an issue with that query.

Comment: I'm currently having some issues with my xdebug. When I try to debug any file it tells me that it is 'Waiting for Connection (netbeans-xdebug)' in the bottom right of the window. I will have to resolve this first before I can try your suggestion. If I can figure it out today then I will get back to you tomorrow. Thanks again for all your help today. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @klm10 You're very welcome! Sometimes my xdebug gets bogged down and the only thing that cures it is if I stop WAMP (if you are on Windows) or LAMP (if you are on Linux) and then start it up again. It's almost like constant debugging starts to clog up the pipes in xdebug!

Comment: I was able to get my xdebug working within Netbeans again. I needed to include some code in my php.ini file that pointed to the dll file. But when I'm debugging through the script up until the `mysqli_query($conn,$query)` statement and I paste the $query statement in the SQL part of phpmyadmin within the correct data table it tells me it's `loading...` and it loads until I stop debug in Netbeans. Once the debug is released it doesn't remember any of the $div, $l1l2, etc variables and tells me "#1054-Unknown column '$div' in 'field list'.

Comment: @klm10 to get the actual value of `$query` you'll have to look at the `variables window` in Netbeans. If you don't have it on your screen, go to `Window -> Debugger -> Variables`... Then you can get the actual value with the resolved variables (instead of `$div`)

Comment: Ok Thanks, let me give that a try

Comment: I set a watch on the `$query` variable in Netbeans then posted the insert statement into phpmyadmin and received this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"INSERT INTO depdivisions (div_id,l1l2_id,l2_id,l1l3_id,l2l3_id,exec_ at line 1`

Comment: I removed the " " that I had around the entire insert statement in phpmyadmin and it added it successfully. Now, I'm working on the grid. I'll let you know

Comment: I'm still unable to add to the grid. I'll have to pick up where I left off on Monday. Enjoy your weekend!

Comment: Hello @FastTrack I've modified my insert and update statements. Currently, I'm capable of successfully editing but for some reason the edit dialog box does not want to close after I click submit and it saves to the grid. As for my add, I am still unable to add.

Comment: Hello there, I want posted data in same page. So, What I should give into `editurl`.