# How to Save data to DB after editing or adding rows in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have been trying to follow demos of http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html, Row Edidting and Live Data Manipulation. I am able to edit rows, save them temporarily in jqgrid and able to get the popup window to add new row.

I am populating my jqgrid with json objects.

1) While doing edit in rows, using below code

```
onSelectRow: function(rowid, status) {                  
     if(rowid && rowid!==lastsel){ 
         if (lastsel != null && !myRowIsValid(lastsel) ) {
             return;
         }                               
         jQuery("#grid").saveRow(lastsel,true,'clientArray');  
         jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('editRow',rowid,true); 
         lastsel=rowid; 
     }
```

},

After pressing Enter or selecting some other row, I can see that my last selected row is holding what I had entered. But how to save all edidted data back to DB??

2)  By using below code to add new row into jqgrid, I am able to get the popup where I see all my columns. But when I press submit, after filling data, I get 'error status 'not found'. error code 404' at top of the window.

```
jQuery("#bedata").click(function(){
    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",{
        height:420,             
        reloadAfterSubmit:false,                
        closeAfterAdd:false,
        errorTextFormat:"Something Went Wrong",
        afterSubmit : function(response,postdata){ 
          alert("hi");
        }
    });         
});
```

Note :-  I have editUrl:"/somejsp.html" in jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({...}) piece of code and corresponding to this I have one controller ready in my Spring MVC Controller class.

I have seen lot of posts where people are saving data back to DB. But my problem is, in almost every post they are using PHP. I do not work in PHP. Could any body please tell me that how to add rows in grid temporarily and at last press one button and save all newly added or edited rows back to DB at once.

But first what am I doing wrong while adding new row?

Please let me know, if you want any other information.

Comment: i think you don't have your `editurl:"the url"` applied in that jqgrid.

Comment: @Jai, new info added. I had forgot earlier.

Comment: what do you have in your editurl?

Comment: I tired two things. 1) editurl: "/data_save.php" where 'data_save.php' is an empty php file in my application because somewehre I read that we need to keep one empty file. 2) editurl: "/datasave.jsp" and I do not have any such jsp in my applcation.

Comment: i think this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382632/jqgrid-how-to-use-editurl

Comment: They have used PHP. Cann't we keep data temporarily in grid and on submit save all new data to DB?

Comment: so what, you are also using a serverside so that should not be issue with you.

Comment: but for that you have to have some kind of add button.

Comment: Ok few more doubts, so you mean if I prepare my php file with proper data then my flow will start working!! Same php file for both edit/add? 1) When my data will be saved If I make some edits, when I edit one row and move my pointer to other row, this time? 2) While adding, When my data will be saved!! When I press submit button?

Comment: Do you know, where to keep this php file. In application or in server. If server, then where in server?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering in a question, but why don't you want to use PHP?

Furthermore, the someurl.php is found relative to your index.php. Since I'm using CodeIgniter(MVP) it's found in my Controllers folder. Try writing it like this:

```
editurl: someurl,
```

I don't know why, but writing it as

```
editurl:someurl.php,
```

doesn't work.

Lastly, my someurl.php contains the sql queries needed to save the data to my database.

E.g.

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO tblclient (clientCode, clientName) VALUES ('$Code', '$Name')");
```

Voila, you're done!

Comment: Altus, Thanks for replying but I have solved this :)

Comment: That's great to know! My answer then goes for other people who might have the same question as you did. So upvote or something haha. Thank you again!